# autocomplete address field using HERE Map api

Tags: javascript, here-api

How to get autocomplete addresses when i enter a text in textbox using HERE MAP API. I used the Retrieve Location Details for a Suggestion i got the values but how to use this in a Web Form.

In Google maps this is done by the Place Autocomplete Service - does anyone know to display the suggestion list in a panel within HERE maps? Is there any javascript api?

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Geocoder Autocomplete API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder-autocomplete/topics/what-is.html) which allows you to autocomplete addresses.

Since it is available as a REST API, you would need to make HTTP calls from your JavaScript application. Please refer to the guide and API reference as necessary. The documentation also contains an [example](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoding_suggestions)

The gist of the example is this call:

```
https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json
  ?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
  &app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE 
  &query=Sawai+pra
  &beginHighlight=<b>
  &endHighlight=</b>
```